# MEAN stack: sending a string to client through a web service, can't access my string

Tags: angularjs, web-services, parameter-passing, mean-stack

Like the title says, I need a web service to send a string back to the client. I'll give you a little code example.
This is my route file:

```
/*log.js*/
            var express = require('express');
            var router = express.Router();

            router.get('/myRoute', function(req, res){
                var greeting = "Hello there!";
                res.json({"myMsg" : greetings});
            }

            module.exports = router;
```

And this is my angular controller:

```
/*functions.js*/
            app.factory('greetFactory', function($resource){
                return $resource('/log/myRoute');
            });

            app.controller('GreetCtrl', function(greetFactory){
                this.getGreetings = function(){
                    var msg = greetFactory.get();
                    console.log(msg);
                    console.log(msg.myMsg);
                };
            });
```

The function is called by pressing a button in a html file, I won't exemplify that part. The problem is that I cannot get the parameter myMsg from the msg variable, here's what the program prints:

```
    e {$promise: d, $resolved: false, toJSON: function, $get: function, $save: function…}
        $promise: d
        $resolved: true
        myMsg: "Hello there!"
        __proto__: e
    undefined
```

Am I missing something? Why can't I get the value of the property "myMsg"?

EDIT: Sorry for the bad grammar/typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an undefined message because the request hasn't yet been resolved by the server at the moment where you call `console.log(msg.myMsg)`.

According to the official [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick
>   since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then
>   rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering,
>   once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated
>   with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the
>   new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a
>   callback function for the action methods.
>
> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be
>   invoked with the following parameters:
>
> HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success],
>   [error]) non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters],
>   postData, [success], [error]) non-GET instance actions:
>   instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])

So technically you don't need a callback function when you call the $resource *get* method, however you can add one like so:

```
this.getGreetings = function(){
    var msg = greetFactory.get(function() {
        console.log(msg.myMsg);
    });
    console.log(msg);
};
```

Comment: OMG I can't believe I didn't realize it :S Thank you man, worked like a charm!